# Metapost External Figure

Tags: graphics, external-files, metapost

I have a metapost file `image.mp` containing the following lines:

```
beginfig(0);
draw p0; 
externalfigure "/Users/dsg/tex/images/image.png" xyscaled r0 shifted r1; 
endfig;
```

When I run `mptopdf scene.mp` I get the following error:

```
MPtoPDF 1.4.1 : running 'mpost --mem=mpost   --tex=latex  scene.mp'
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.1.0)
(mpost.mp (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004)) (./scene.mp
>> externalfigure
! Isolated expression.
<to be read again> 
                   "/Users/dsg/tex/images/image.png"
l.421 ...tex/images/image.png"
                                                   xyscaled r0 shifted r1;
```

I think it is being caused the new version of metapost on my new computer because this same file used to work on my old computer.

I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried changing it to:

```
beginfig(0);
draw p0; 
draw externalfigure "/Users/dsg/tex/images/image.png" xyscaled r0 shifted r1; 
endfig;
```

But then I get:

```
MPtoPDF 1.4.1 : running 'mpost --mem=mpost   --tex=latex  scene.mp'
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.1.0)
(mpost.mp (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004)) (./scene.mp
>> externalfigure
! Improper `addto'.
<to be read again> 
                   withpen
draw->...:also(EXPR0)else:doublepath(EXPR0)withpen
                                                  .currentpen.fi._op_
<to be read again> 
                   "/Users/dsg/tex/images/image.png"
l.421 ...images/image.png"
                                                   xyscaled r0 shifted r1;
```

(EDIT: added `beginfig(0);`)

SOLVED: you do not need `draw externalfigure ...` just `externalfigure ...`, but as @egreg put it, you need to run `mptopdf -metafun`

Comment: Could you please add a complete example, from `beginfig` to `endfig`?

Comment: Are you sure it is `draw externalfigure` and not only `externalfigure`? And are you running `mptopdf -metafun`?

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I was not running with the `-metafun` flag. It now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to announce the Metapost format you want to use (your log shows you're using the default `plain.mp`, also known as `mpost.mp`). So the call should be

```
mptopdf -metafun file
```

(see the [man page at Contextgarden](http://minimals.contextgarden.net/current/bin/man/man/html/mptopdf.html))

According to the documentation, it's just

```
externalfigure "file" ...;
```

not with `draw` in front. You find something in the section "Including graphics" of [the Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf), pages 350ff.

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation?

Comment: This answer might be outdated.  At least nowadays `externalfigure` returns a `picture`, so you need to use `draw` with it.