# How to insert (if possible) an image inside a Metapost figure? (in plain LaTeX environment)

Tags: metapost, metafun

I'd like to insert an image into a Metapost figure (I'm using MikTeX/LaTeX, no Metafun). I hopefully tried (also thanks to Aditya's suggestion) the following Metapost code (compiled with `-tex=pdftex` option):

```
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
etex

beginfig(1);
picture pct;
pct:=btex \includegraphics{myimage.jpg} etex;
%pct:=btex \includegraphics{myimage.eps} etex;
draw pct;
endfig;
end
```

but it does not work, giving error `! Unable to make mpx file.` if I use `jpg` format, or no error but neither image if I use `eps` format. Any clue?

**UPDATE: trying the Metafun way without ConTeXt**

I was told (see egreg comment below) that I can use the `externalfigure` command of Metafun (I use LaTeX, so I do not deal with Metafun, which, if I understand, is ConTeXt specific), using the `mpost -mem=metafun` compiling option of Metapost, but my system (Windows 7, MikTeX/LaTeX) seems to be unaware of Metafun and tells me `Sorry, I can't find the 'metafun' preload file; will try 'plain'.`, the actual error being `! Isolated expression.` referred to `externalfigure`. How can I install Metafun inside MikTeX?

Here is my Metapost code compiled with `-mem=metafun` and `-tex=pdftex` options:

```
verbatimtex
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
etex

beginfig(1);
externalfigure "myimage.jpg";
endfig;
end
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: With `metafun` you can use external images (see [Metapost external figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98514/metapost-external-figure)), but, according to the Metafun manual (linked in the answer), it's not possible to store an image in a `picture` variable.

Comment: I guess I can't use Metafun with MikTeX/LaTeX, isn't it?

Comment: Why not? `mpost -mem=metafun`

Comment: To prevent any confusion: ConTeXt MkII and `mptopdf` use the `externalfigure` syntax *without* draw. ConTeXt MkIV requires the `draw externalfigure` syntax.

Comment: @Marco I'm talking about Metapost, not ConTeXt. With `most -mem=metafun` I get an error if I use `draw externalfigure`.

Comment: @egreg Indeed. I think I didn't make myself clear. `externalfigure` works with MetaFun when used from `mpost`, `mptopdf` or ConTeXt MkII, adding `draw` is wrong in that case. For future visitors which are ConTeXt MkIV users I added the information that `draw externalfigure` is required if MetaFun is used in MkIV. This change led to some confusion before and is barely documented. The OP however, must not use the `draw` syntax.

Comment: What if I get from Metapost the error message `Sorry, I can't find the 'metafun' preload file; will try 'plain'.`? Where should I take Metafun from?

Comment: Please create a complete minimal working example. Did you load a latex preable that calls the graphics package? Vanilla MP generates tex labels using dvi output, so inclusion of jpg files will not work. You need to covert jpg to eps first.

Comment: @egreg you were able to write gmp, why don't you add this fundamental feature to your package? ;)

Comment: @mmj You can already use `metafun` with `gmp` and so `externalfigure`.

Comment: @egreg The problem is that, my fault, I was not able to find `metafun.mp` anywhere on the web. I hope I don't have to install the whole ConTeXt just to have Metafun.

Comment: Do not compile your code with `--tex=pdftex`. You need LaTeX macro-package (since you are using `\includegraphics`) and DVI output (since that is what plain MP understands), so you need to compile using `--tex=latex` (or just leave off that option as the `%&latex` directive already uses latex).

Answer (score 4):

### Proper Answer

**Note** I deleted my previous answer, because this is a working solution:

Use the following MP file

```
beginfig(1);
externalfigure "hacker.jpg" scaled 3cm;
endfig;
end;
```

and compile it using

```
mptopdf --metafun filename
```

This will generate the following `filename.1` file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 86 86 
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 85.03935 85.03935 
%%Creator: MetaPost 1.504
%%CreationDate: 2013.04.14:1210
%%Pages: 1
%%BeginProlog
%%BeginResource: procset mpost
/bd{bind def}bind def
/hlw{0 dtransform exch truncate exch idtransform pop setlinewidth}bd
/vlw{0 exch dtransform truncate idtransform setlinewidth pop}bd
/l{lineto}bd/r{rlineto}bd/c{curveto}bd/m{moveto}bd/p{closepath}bd/n{newpath}bd
/C{setcmykcolor}bd/G{setgray}bd/R{setrgbcolor}bd/lj{setlinejoin}bd/ml{setmiterlimit}bd
/lc{setlinecap}bd/S{stroke}bd/F{fill}bd/q{gsave}bd/Q{grestore}bd/s{scale}bd/t{concat}bd
/sd{setdash}bd/rd{[] 0 setdash}bd/P{showpage}bd/B{q F Q}bd/W{clip}bd
%%EndResource
%%EndProlog
%%Page: 1 1
%%MetaPostSpecials: 2.0 123 1000
%%MetaPostSpecial: 9 85.03935 0 0 85.03935 0 0 hacker.jpg 1 10
 0.123 0.012 0.001 R
n 0 0 m
0 0 l
0 0 l
0 0 l
 p F
P
%%EOF
```

and a `filename-1.pdf` file that includes the image.

Comment: Thanks, I confirm that your code doesn't show any error but neither the image insertion. Anyway, if I can't get to this with LaTeX/Metapost, I'll go with tikz.

Comment: Tentative upvote…

Comment: What about the Metafun way? Can you help me to understand how to install Metafun on LaTeX?

Comment: To use metafun, simply add `input mp-tool.mpii`. But this will notmwork with latex as it needs supports from the macro package, and LaTeX dors not provide that.

Comment: So I have to install ConTeXt (or what else) to run your Metapost code with `mptopdf` and `--metafun` option?

Comment: @mmj: I don't use Miktex, so I don't know what is the best way to install `mptopdf`. Doesn't Miktex's GUI list it as one of the packages? If not, perhaps you could post that as a separate question so that it attracts attention of Miktex users.

Answer (score 1):

### A modern answer

I know this is old, but with `luamplib` and `lualatex` there is now a much simpler and more useable way to include external images in a Metapost drawing.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    picture A; 
    A = TEX("\includegraphics[width=200pt]{example-image-a}");

    % alternative, if you like btex ... etex 
    % A = btex \includegraphics[width=200pt]{example-image-a} etex;
    
    draw A;
    
    % add a grid (to help you measure the coordinates)
    numeric wd, ht; 
    (wd, ht) = urcorner A;
    for x=0 step 10 until wd:
        draw (x, -6) -- (x, ht + 6)
            withcolor if x mod 100 = 0: red else: 7/8 fi;
    endfor
    for y=0 step 10 until ht:
        draw (-6, y) -- (wd + 6, y)
            withcolor if y mod 100 = 0: red else: 7/8 fi;
    endfor
    
    % add a label (or whatever)
    dotlabel.urt("Label here", (125, 133));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

compile this with `lualatex` to produce a PDF file like this:

[image]

You can (of course) remove the grid once you are happy with the position of your labels or other annotations.  The picture produced by the `TEX()` macro (or by `btex ... etex` is a regular MP `<picture>` object, so you can scale it, rotate it, shift it etc as required.